# Mapping data with dynamic variables

Tags: javascript

I am having a little trouble trying to achieve something.  So I have some data

```
let data = [
  {
    "ID": 123456,
    "Date": "2012-01-01",
    "Irrelevant_Column_1": 123,
    "Irrelevant_Column_2": 234,
    "Irrelevant_Column_3": 345,
    "Irrelevant_Column_4": 456
  },
  ...
]
```

And I wanted to remove the irrelevant columns.  So someone suggested using map

```
data = data.map(element => ({ID: element.ID, Date: element.Date}))
```

The problem is, I dont want to define the columns.  I have the user select the columns to keep, and assign them to a variable.  I can then do something like

```
let selectedId = this.selectedIdCol;
```

The issue is, I am unable to now use this within the map.  I am trying

```
let selectedId = this.selectedIdCol;
this.parsed_csv = data.map(element => (
    {ID: element.selectedId, Date: element.Date}
));
```

But that does not seem to work, just returns the date. Also, my IDE is saying that the variable is unused.  So how can I use the `selectedId` variable as part of the map function?

Thanks

Comment: element[selectedId]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do using [`Bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) notation and helper function

Whenever you want to use variable to access property you need to use `[]` notation.

```js
let data = [{"ID": 123456,"Date": "2012-01-01","column_1": 123,"column_2": 234,"column_3": 345,"column_4": 456},{"ID": 123456,"Date": "2018-10-01",   "column_1": 123,"column_2": 234,"column_3": 345,"column_4": 46},]

function selectDesired(data,propName1,propName2){
  return data.map(e=> ({[propName1]: e[propName1], [propName2]: e[propName2]}))
}

console.log(selectDesired(data, 'Date', 'column_4'))
```

Comment: At first I thought about this solution but OP's attempt involved `ID: element.selectedId` which confused me on his real intention

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly.  I was using a . because all examples I saw used dots.

Answer (score -1):

The basic technique is illustrated here, assuming that the user's selected column_name is "ID"

```js
let data = [
     {
       "ID": 123456,
       "Date": "2012-01-01",
       "Irrelevant_Column_1": 123,
       "Irrelevant_Column_2": 234,
       "Irrelevant_Column_3": 345,
       "Irrelevant_Column_4": 456
     }
];
let column_name = "ID";
let curated = data.map(element=>({[column_name]: element[column_name]}));
   
console.log(curated)
```

If you are wanting the user to be able to multi-select their columns,(assuming data from above is still in scope)

```js
let user_selection = ["ID","Date"];
let curated = data.map(
   (element)=>
   {
      let item = {};
      user_selection.forEach(
         (property)=>
         {
           item[property] = element[property];
         }
      return item;
   }
);
```

To set up a function that can handle multiple calling situations without having a monstrously hack-and-patched source history, set up the function's signature to receive a spread list of properties.

If you wish to extend the capabilities to accept

- a csv property list
- an array of property names delivered directly
- an array of property names

you can assume the properties argument in the signature to be an iterable of property groupings, having the most basic grouping be a singleton.

Commentary embedded within the sample code to expound in more detail

```
 var getProjection = (data,...properties) =>
 {
     //+=================================================+
     // Initialize the projection which will be returned
     //+=================================================+
     let projection = {};

     //+=================================================+
     // Set up the property mapping func
     //+=================================================+
     let safe_assign = (source, target ,propertyDesignator)=>
     {
        if(source[propertyDesignator])
        {
           target[propertyDesignator] = source[propertyDesignator];
        }
     };

     //+=====================================================+
     // Iterate the properties list, assuming each element to
     // be a property grouping
     //+=====================================================+
     properties.forEach(
        (propertyGroup)=>
        {
           //+-----------------------------------------------+
           // If the propertyGroup is not an array, perform
           // direct assignment
           //+-----------------------------------------------+
           if(!Array.isArray(propertyGroup))
           {
              //+-------------------------------------------+
              //Only map the requested property if it exists
              //+-------------------------------------------+
              safe_assign(data,projection,propertyGroup);
           }


           //+-----------------------------------------------+
           // If the propertyGroup *is* an array, iterate it
           // This technique obviously assumes that your
           // property groupings are only allowed to be one
           // level deep. This is for accommodating distinct
           // calling conventions, not for supporting a deeply
           // nested object graph. For a deeper object graph,
           // the technique would largely be the same, but
           // you would need to recurse.
           //+-----------------------------------------------+
           if( Array.isArray(propertyGroup))
           {
              propertyGroup.forEach(
                 (property)=>
                 { 
                    safe_assign(data,projection,property);
                 }
           }
       }
    );
    //+===================================+
    // Return your projection
    //+===================================+
    return projection;
 };


 //+--------------------------------------+
 //Now let's test
 //+--------------------------------------+
 let data = [
   {ID:1,Foo:"Foo1",Bar:"Bar1",Baz:"Inga"},
   {ID:2,Foo:"Foo2",Bar:"Bar2",Baz:"Ooka"},
   {ID:3,Foo:"Foo3",Bar:"Bar3",Baz:"oinga",Floppy:"Floop"},
   {ID:4,Foo:"Foo4",Good:"Boi",Bar:"Bar3"Baz:"Baz"}
 ];


 //***************************************
 //tests
 //***************************************

 var projection1 = getProjection(data.find(first=>first),"ID","Baz"));//=>{ID:1,Baz:"Inga"}

 var projection2 = getProjection(data[0],["ID","Baz"]);//=>{ID:1,Baz:"Inga"}
 var projection3 = getProjection(data[0],...["ID","Baz"]);//=>{ID:1,Baz:"Inga"}


 var user_selected_properties = ["ID","Good","Baz"];

 var projections = data.map(element=>getProjection(element,user_selected_properties));
 //+=====================================+
 // projections = 
 // [
 //    {ID:1,Baz:"Inga"},
 //    {ID:2,Baz:"Ooka"},
 //    {ID:3,Baz:"oinga"},
 //    {ID:4,Good:"Boi",Baz:"Baz"}
 // ];
 //+=====================================+
```

Comment: I would like to know why this answer has been downvoted. If it states inaccurate information, explain what is inaccurate.

Comment: As to the final example, I try to avoid conditionally branching code which processes one way for a list and a different way for a single instance. I instead detect the singular case, wrap in an array then process through the sole logical route. I did not do that here since this question indicates the asker is a beginner. But I can edit to provide "what I would actually write in my own source" if someone explicitly requests it.

Comment: ...I don't usually care about points on the Interwebz, but I'm still wanting to know what was considered wrong about this answer that deserved a downvote. Explain to me what is incorrect about it.